# Prove this equality in a Hilbert Space $H$ with Riesz's Representation Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

For $x \in H$, prove that $\sup_{\|z\| = 1} \langle x , z \rangle= \| x \|$

Here is a quick one. If someone could improve this it would be great

> **Proof**
>
> By Cauchy Schwarz, $\langle x,z \rangle \leq \|x \| \|z \| \implies \sup_{ \| z \|  = 1} \langle x,z \rangle \leq \|x \|$
>
> Conversely, take $z_0=\frac{x}{\| x \|}$.
>
> $\langle x, z_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{\|x\|}\langle x,x\rangle = \|x \|\leq \sup_{\| z \| = 1} \langle x, z \rangle$
>
> By Riesz's Theorem, $\exists x \in H$ s.t $f(z)=\langle x,z \rangle$ and $\| x\|= \| f \|$. So $\|f \|= \sup_{\| z \| =1} | f(z)| = \| x \|$

**EDIT** is that enough?

**EDIT2**: Why is it superfluous?

Comment: You can't beat that. But Riesz says that the dual of $H$ is isometric to $H$ via $x\longmapsto (x,\cdot)$. You got the isometry part. It remains to show that every bounded linear functional on $H$ is of this form.

Comment: I try and edit. Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you need Riesz's theorem at all for this.  The first three lines of your proof show the desired statement (by giving you both inequalities).  The last line is superfluous.

Comment: My instructor says there should be more detail and this is just a sketch

Comment: The only detail I noticed that was missing is the $x = 0$ case for the converse.

Comment: If $x = 0$, isn 't it immediately true?

Comment: My first thought was defining a linear functional $f(x)=\sup_{z} <x,z>$ and go from there with Riesz, but I don't know if that does what you want.

Comment: Show me please?